# get data from sql server db

Tags: asp.net

is that a good practice?

```
public static void GetToolData(int TD_ID,out string pageH1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Util.GetConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            GetToolData(con,TD_ID, out pageH1);
        }
    }


    internal static void GetToolData(SqlConnection con,  int TD_ID, out string pageH1)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetToolData", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TD_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TD_ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TD_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            pageH1 = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@TD_Name"].Value);

        }
    }
```

or maybe there is better way to do that?

Comment: looks ok. Is there anythin specific that you are looking for ?

Comment: Why separate the `SqlConnection` from the `SqlCommand`? I would create both inside the internal method.

Comment: marc_s - how you think i need to combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as, when you're calling GetToolData(), you keep your connection in a using this should be fine.